# PHPExcel Writter optional number of cells like GA

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

Can somebody tell me please how to generate column indexes (like BB) if the number of cells is optional? Currently my code explicitly sets the cell like

```
$list->setCellValue("D1", "Date"));
```

but is there a way to generate column index **"D"** automatically or not? I would like to have col index like GA it  means from A to Z and than double the char part if columns number exceeds the range of A-Z. Is PHPExcel able to generate this indexes automatically or not?

Answer (score 0):

```
$colIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($cell->getColumn());
```

Instead of using `$cell->getColumn()` you can set your letter manually

Comment: But *$cell->getColumn()* generates the number representation of coll index. My question was if there is a way to get index like AA.

Comment: @Čamo `$columnAddress = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex(26);` will give `AA`;

Comment: But if you're counting via letters; then `$column = 'Z'; $column++; echo $column;` will give you `AA`.... PHP handles string incrementing in a Perl-style (which is usefl for Excel columns)

Comment: $string++ is interesting. Z really gives an AA Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So for now I has to write a function to do this:

```
public static function indexToExcelIndex( $index )
{
    $div = intdiv( $index, 26 );
    $modulo = $index % 26;
    $result = '';
    do
    {
        $result .= chr( 65 + $modulo );
    }
    while( --$div > -1 );

    return $result;
}
```

**EDIT:** As find out there is a method **setCellValueByColumnAndRow()** which accepts numeric coordinates of col and row. So I dont need alphabetical coordinates.

Comment: There's a more efficient built-in version of your function: `PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex();`